# Can I pair multiple hosts to a single Bluetooth headphones device?

Tags: bluetooth

I have a pair of Bluetooth headphones which I'd like to use with my phone and computer. They are currently paired with the computer and are working fine. Is it possible to pair them additionally with my phone, maintaining both pairings, so that I can use the device with either  of the hosts without repairing every time I want to use them?

I have a Creative AIRWAVE Bluetooth speaker at home which I've paired with multiple phones at the same time, I'm just wondering if I can do this with *any* Bluetooth device.

Comment: Related: https://www.howtogeek.com/297281/how-to-connect-your-bluetooth-headphones-to-more-than-one-device-at-a-time/

Comment: How come this question got so many up-votes which is supposed to only be given to "those question shows research effort..."? The OP did his research, though, but only while answering his own question in the currently chosen answer.

Comment: Another related information on one particular brand to demonstrate what could be possible, although that would be different "model by model, brand by brand": https://phiaton.com/blogs/audio/bluetooth-multipoint-pairing-what-is-it-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: You probably want multipoint bluetooth.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As it turns out, **yes, you can pair multiple "hosts" with a single device.**

Once the device has been connected to device A, connection attempts from device B will fail.

In my case, I've set my Android phone to not automatically connect to the Bluetooth device. Whenever I want to use it, I disconnect it (not unpair) from my computer and then attempt a connection from my phone, and vice-versa.

TL;DR: It works.

Comment: It's inconvenient; it should just connect to both and mix the audio. This doesn't really count as connecting with multiple hosts!  Imagine if the Internet worked that way. Can I connect to multiple hosts? Yes, but you have to close all the sockets to one host before opening them to tne other ...  can't call that "multiple" with a straight face.

Comment: I have 2 BT headsets (an old Mpow + a new Lenovo). Mpow can be connected to both, the phone and PC, but not Lenovo (which is strange as the Mpow is 3 years old, and the Lenovo is new).

Answer (score 12):

At least some Bluetooth headphones can maintain a simultaneous connection to two devices. For example, with the Bose headphones I just purchased, I can simultaneously connect to my phone and my laptop, and play music on either one without unpairing/pairing or switching Bluetooth on/off. Starting music on one device stops the music on the other device.
I suggest downloading a copy of the user's manual for the headphones you are considering, and reading it carefully to determine if they support this functionality.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a simultaneous "pairing" and not a simultaneous "connection"?  "Starting music on one device stops the music on the other device" means that one connection kicks the other connection off?

Comment: @endolith It is lame indeed; simultaneous means the audio is mixed.

Comment: @Kaz, are you aware of any BT headphones that mix the audio from multiple sources in the way you describe? I've been looking and can't find any that will do that.

Comment: Different headphones handle this slightly differently. But they actually do maintain a connection to multiple devices at once. For example, my Drop+THX Pandas will be connected to both my PC and Android. Both devices show the headphones as connected and display the battery status. But if I play music on both devices, I only hear it from one of the devices. When I pause the music on my PC, the headphones will notice that nothing is coming from the PC and switch to playing the music from my Android.